# Hibernate not generating unique constraint

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I have the following entity on which I would like the column name to be unique. For some reason, Hibernate is not generating any unique constraint when autogenerating the table. Any ideas as to why Hibernate is not enforcing this unique constraint? I'm running MySQL 5.5 and Hibernate 4.2.0 on JBoss EAP 6.1.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Address", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "Name" }))
public class AddressEntity {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String streetAddress;
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String zip;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "Name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // getters and setters...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `uniqueConstraint` from `@Table`.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately that doesn't work. I tried different combinations. First with @Column(name = "Name", unique = true), then with @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "Name" }), then with both, then with @Column(name = "Name", unique = true, nullable = false). Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try putting this on `setters` or `variable` instead of `getters`.

Comment: your `@column` is from `javax.persistence` and not from `org.springframework` or `hibernate`?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to keep the code provider-neutral. That's why I'm using javax.persistence annotations.

Comment: I suggest you to debug using hibernate property `hibernate.show_sql`.

Comment: Turns out this is a defect in Hibernate 4.2.0 when using the option hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update in persistence.xml. See bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8109

This defect is fixed in Hibernate 4.2.1.

Using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create, Hibernate successfully created the unique constraints.

Comment: If you make some changes in `Entity`, then you should set `hbm2dll.auto` to `create`. `Update` will definitely create problems.